# mysql INSERT abysmal performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm iterating over about 14,000 records which I get from csv file.
For each user I do this:

1) I create a user record in `users` table
2) I insert ~21 attributes for that user into `users_attributes` table

Initially each user takes ~2 seconds to be inserted, but after awhile insertion time grows to ~50 seconds... and so script takes forever....

Why is it so slow?

Example insert statement:

**Executed once:**

```
INSERT INTO users (uname, email, pass, passreminder, activated, approved_date, approved_by, user_regdate, lastlogin, theme, ublockon, ublock, tz, locale) VALUES ('someid_example.com', 'someid@example.com', 'test', 'User-generated', -32768, '2014-09-03 14:41:50', 2, '2014-09-03 14:41:50', '1970-01-01 00:00:00', '', 0, '', '', '');
```

**Repeated 21 times:**

```
INSERT INTO users_attributes (name, value, user_id) VALUES ('user_information_address', 'some address', 9862);
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `uname` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `pass` varchar(138) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `passreminder` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `activated` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
    `approved_date` datetime NOT NULL,
    `approved_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `user_regdate` datetime NOT NULL,
    `lastlogin` datetime NOT NULL,
    `theme` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `ublockon` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
    `ublock` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `tz` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `locale` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),user
    KEY `uname` (`uname`),
    KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `users_attributes` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `value` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`name`),
    KEY `IDX_SOMENUM` (`user_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `IDX_SOMENUM` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Show us your INSERT statement.

Comment: Indexes are slowing inserts down. If you also insert user IDs, insert them first without indexes, then in the end add the keys and indexes to your table.

Comment: 2 seconds for any single insert is a lifetime. Something is wrong there too.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ive' added example inserts

Comment: How is your server configuration? A low memory server is a nightmare for any database server.

Comment: ThoriumBR 2Gb ram server.

Comment: why on earth are you doing this one record at a time? Can you use some sort of bulk insert to put the csv to a staging table and doian insert using a select? Some databases even let you directly query teh csv without the staging table. Never do anything row by row that you can do in a set-based manner.

Comment: Well, you need to figure out how to get a single insert down to a small fraction of a second first.  2 seconds is an eternity, and if this is the first time you've attempted an insert, almost anything could be wrong, including your Ethernet connection.

Comment: @HLGEM: It shouldn't be taking 2 seconds to do a single record insertion.

Comment: @RobertHarvey but it's in effect 22 inserts for a single user... Would that take ~2 seconds?

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because it inserts into users table, and then it inserts 21 times into users_attributes table. It's all for a single user.

Comment: It still shouldn't be taking 2 seconds.

Comment: @HLGEM This is not my code. I've been asked to debug it. And the first thing I said - "why on earth are they doing 22 inserts in a  loop" without transactions.

Comment: So what happens when you put it in a transaction?

Comment: @RobertHarvey the issue is - this is not my code. Original developer was using Doctrine and the rest of the app is kind of a black box. I haven't tried transactions yet. ehh - I guess that's my next step then.

Comment: Tried first query with your tables (the second one fails because of a constraint error, but I realize it was just an example), it takes 0.07 seconds. How many rows do you have in the table? Transactions or no transactions, it should not take 2 seconds.

Comment: @MatsKindahl I've profiled the script again - and there is also a memory leak. So I think I'm gonna end up completely rewriting the thing suing raw PDO prepared statements and transactions.